# React Leaflet - Rotating ImageOverlay React Component by n degrees

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-leaflet

**Goal:** 
I'm using React Leaflet to build a game map and I'm placing game tiles using ImageOverlay, the problem is leaflet doesn't allow you to rotate pieces. I need to be able to place ImageOverlays rotated by a degree.

**What I've tried:**
I'm using ImageOverlay to create the map because the pieces are PNG files placed by their center coordinates. Then the ones rotated I gave a class with the name 'rotate'. Then on 'componentDidMount' I tried to find the elements with that class name using 'ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getElementsByClassName('rotate${degree}')' but that doesn't work on React components?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // Below code returns empty arrays
    let elementsRotated90 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getElementsByClassName("rotate90");
    let elementsRotated180 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getElementsByClassName("rotate180");
    let elementsRotated270 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getElementsByClassName("rotate270");
  }

  render() {
    let position = [this.state.lat, this.state.long];
    return (
      <Map className="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <LayerGroup>
          {map1
            .data
            .Pieces
            .Stages
            .map(stage => {
              return stage
                .Tiles
                .map(tile => {
                  let height = tile.Resolution.Height;
                  let width = tile.Resolution.Width;
                  let url = require('./assets/pieces/' + tile.Type + '.png');
                  let rotation = tile.Rotation;
                  let center = tile.CenterCoord;
                  let bound = ([
                    [
                      center[1] - height / 2,
                      center[0] - width / 2
                    ],
                    [
                      center[1] + height / 2,
                      center[0] + width / 2
                    ]
                  ]);
                  let component = <ImageOverlay bounds={bound} url={url} 
                  className={`rotate${rotation}`}/>
                  this.state.markers.push(component);
                  return component;
                })
            })}
        </LayerGroup>
     </Map>
     )
  }
```

If anyone has a better idea than what I've tried to do, do let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To rotate [`ImageOverlay` component](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#imageoverlay) the following approach could be considered:

1) get [`L.ImageOverlay` instance](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#imageoverlay) via [`ref` attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
 const { leafletElement: imageOverlay } = this.imageOverlayRef.current;
```

where

```
 <ImageOverlay
        ref={this.imageOverlayRef}
        ...
 />
```

2) get `Image` element and apply [`rotateZ()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateZ):

```
const image = imageOverlay.getElement()
this.rotateImage(image, this.rotateAngle);
```

where

```
rotateImage(image, angle) {
    if (!this.originalTransformValue) {
      this.originalTransformValue = image.style.transform;
    }
    image.style.transform = `${this.originalTransformValue} rotateZ(${angle}deg)`;
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gs7srt) for your reference

Answer (score 0):

In react leaflet V4, this solution does not work for dynamic content. The initial transform erasse the new transform after a few seconds